# Derive a part of a date from a text column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to derive the weekday from a text column in SQLite my current code is:

```
SELECT VendorID, 
tpep_dropoff_datetime
DATEPART(weekday,tpep_dropoff_datetime) AS Weekday
FROM trips;
```

In which tpep_dropoff_datetime is a text column with this as text '2020-01-16 21:48:35'.

The result I want is an extra column which is called weekday which returns 0 to 6 for Sunday till Saturday as a value. I hope anyone can help me.. thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `strftime()` does with the format `'%w'`:

```
strfime('%w', tpep_dropoff_datetime) as weekday
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I do not really understand what I am supposed to do with the strfime?

Comment: @Django Whatever you were trying to do with that non-standard-sqlite `datepart()` function.

Comment: @Django . . . `datepart()` is a bespoke function in SQL Server.  It has nothing to do with SQLite.  `strfime()` is a bespoke function in SQLite that happens to do what you want.  Date/time functions are notoriously database dependent.